# How to use the sql server 2012 jdbc jar in spark

Tags: sql-server, azure, jdbc, apache-spark

I have a spark azure hd insight cluster and I want to connect the sparksql to another sql server box .

I can connect it with FREETDS and pymssql but as I understand I should connect it to spark sql via jdbc driver

This is as per this documentation in Spark

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

Now I have the Jar in my home directory 
and if I want to use this Jar its said in the document

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=postgresql-9.3-1102-jdbc41.jar bin/spark-shell
```

which I have used as

```
SPARK_CLASSPATH=./sqljdbc_4.2/enu/sqljdbc42.jar ./bin/spark-shell
```

but it shows

```
-bash: ./bin/spark-shell: No such file or directory
```

However If this is a spark cluster and If I type spark-shell , I always get the shell . 
Please assist

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path /home/XXX/sqljdbc42.jar
```